# Как переопределить кнопку в JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, gui

Подскажите, как для JOptionPane.showMessageDialog() переопределить кнопку, что бы она не закрывала диалог, а вызывала, например, System.exit()?

Comment: А зачем что-то переопределять, если можно int result = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog();
if(result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){System.exit()}

Comment: Так, showMessageDialog() возвращает void

Comment: Точно, с confirmDialog попутал. Ну, так используйте showConfirmDialog/showOptionDialog...

Answer (score 1):

Можно написать `System.exit()` после `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()`:

```java
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Message");
System.exit(0);
```

Единственный нюанс в том, что при нажатии на крестик в *"MessageDialog"* программа всё равно будет закрываться.

В вашем случае лучше подойдёт `showConfirmDialog` или `showOptionDialog`:

```java
int confirm = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Confirm");
if(confirm == 0) System.exit(0);

int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Option","Option", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE,null,null,null);
if(option == 0) System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать следующий код:

```
int option = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog();
if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) System.exit(0);
```

Таким образом можно не только переопределять кнопку ОК, но и Да или Нет с помощью соответсвующих констант.

Comment: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` - это `void`, а не `int`. Этот код не работает.

Comment: Блин, точно, был же коммент насчёт этого( Эх, слона-то я и не приметил :с